# windows batch loop not completing

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

Attempting to have this batch file loop through a list (`list.txt`) and report back a number from the file using `xml.exe` available here:
http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/

File:

```
@echo off

SET USER_NAME=registereduser
SET PASSWORD=secret
SET LIST=list.txt
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

net use * /del /yes > null

FOR /F %%A in ('TYPE "%LIST%"') do (
    NET USE * \\%%A\c$ /user:%USER_NAME% %PASSWORD% > null
    SET DATA=\\%%A\c$\directory here\file.xml
)
SET A_NUM=
FOR /F %%I IN ('bin\xml sel -t -v "//Editable[@name='MachineID.SerialNumber']/@default" "%DATA%"') DO (SET A_NUM=%%I)

IF "%A_NUM%" == "" (
    ECHO ********************************************************
    ECHO *** ERROR : CAN'T CONNECT ***
    ECHO ********************************************************
    GOTO END
) ELSE (
    ECHO A NUMBER FOUND : %A_NUM%
    ECHO.
)
```

Results:

> ```
> A  NUMBER FOUND : 5300
> ```

Expected results:

> ```
> A NUMBER FOUND : 5300
> A NUMBER FOUND : 4100
> A NUMBER FOUND : 2600
> ```

I see it mapping the drives but it doesn't run the script on all the machines.

---edit---

Is this nesting the loop?

```
@echo off

SET USER_NAME=registereduser
SET PASSWORD=secret
SET LIST=list.txt
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

net use * /del /yes > null

FOR /F %%A in ('TYPE "%LIST%"') do (
    NET USE * \\%%A\c$ /user:%USER_NAME% %PASSWORD% > null
    SET DATA=\\%%A\c$\directory here\file.xml

    SET A_NUM=
    FOR /F %%I IN ('bin\xml sel -t -v "//Editable[@name='MachineID.SerialNumber']/@default" "%DATA%"') DO (SET A_NUM=%%I)

    IF "%A_NUM%" == "" (
        ECHO ********************************************************
        ECHO *** ERROR : CAN'T CONNECT ***
        ECHO ********************************************************
        GOTO END
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO A NUMBER FOUND : %A_NUM%
        ECHO.
    )
)
```

Error:

> ```
> > .\anumber2.bat
> failed to load external entity ""
> ********************************************************
> *** ERROR : CAN'T CONNECT ***
> ********************************************************
> The system cannot find the batch label specified - END
> failed to load external entity ""
> ********************************************************
> *** ERROR : CAN'T CONNECT ***
> ********************************************************
> ```

Comment: You need to nest your FOR commands.

Comment: Edited the post. Looks like it got a bit further, but what is it complaining about now?

Comment: You are inside a code block so you need to use delayed expansion for all your environmental variables.  ex: %DATA% to !DATA!

Comment: Do not redirect to `> null`, because this creates a file called `null.`; the *null* device is called `nul` (*one `L`*) in Windows...

Comment: THANK YOU, @aschipfl, that's a big help.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Squashman, I have an answer!

```
@echo off

SET USER_NAME=registereduser
SET PASSWORD=secret
SET LIST=list.txt
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

net use * /del /yes > null

FOR /F %%A in ('TYPE "%LIST%"') do (
    NET USE * \\%%A\c$ /user:%USER_NAME% %PASSWORD% > nul
    SET DATA=\\%%A\c$\directory here\file.xml

    SET A_NUM=
    FOR /F %%I IN ('bin\xml sel -t -v "//Editable[@name='MachineID.SerialNumber']/@default" "!DATA!"') DO (SET A_NUM=%%I)

    IF "!A_NUM!" == "" (
        ECHO ********************************************************
        ECHO *** ERROR : CAN'T CONNECT ***
        ECHO ********************************************************
        GOTO END
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO A NUMBER FOUND : !A_NUM!
        ECHO.
    )
)
```

Result:

> ```
> > .\anumber2.bat
> A NUMBER FOUND : 4100
>
> A NUMBER FOUND : 5300
> ```