# Double and single quote creates issue in Windows batch script to kill process

Tags: node.js, windows, batch-file

I'm using node.js and windows batch script which kills process with particular port.

It kills process very through command line but it doesn't work through batch script. I think it creates problem due to double and single quotes?

As far as below code is concerned, it finds 3000 port in LISTENING state and kills.

```
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :3000.*LISTENING') do (TaskKill.exe /PID %P /T /F)
```

Comment: In a batch file the  percent symbols for the FOR variables are doubled.  Says it right in the help file. **To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead of %variable.**

Comment: Please post this as an answer, i will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

What stands out about your code is that there **MUST** be a space after the `do` keyword.

You don't indicate what string you're trying to locate. It appears to be `:3000`*anynumberofanycharacters*`LISTENING` using the default `/r` switch. I'd prefer that was in "quotes" but it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: I'm sorry about typo of space which i updated now. Thanks for that but my question is when i add same code in batch script in node.js file then it doesn't work. Can someone tell me what is the issue or what fix i need to make?